# Why comparision doesn't work as I suspect? PL/I

Tags: mainframe, pl-i

This comparison prints `'0'b`. Don't understand why... As I know strings are converted automatically to `float` in PL/I if needed.

```
put skip list('-2.34e-1'=-2.34e-1);
```

Comment: What output were you expecting? Is that the exact, as in pasted form the emulator, output you received?

Comment: @BillWoodger I was expecting '1'b

Comment: What is your environment? PL1F under Hercules? PL/I Optimizing Compiler? Another implementation of PL/1 such as the ancient Digital Research CP/M 80 compiler?

Comment: @zarchasmpgmr I am begginer and don't know. But I am working on really mainframe, not hercules emulator

Comment: @zer_ik I did some more research and reworked my answer. See if it explains the problem so you can understand it, else feel free to ask for clarification in the comments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have tested this in our environment (Enterprise PL/I V4.5 on z/OS) and found the same behaviour - under certain compile-options.

Using the option `FLOAT(NODFP)` (i.e. do not use native support for decimal floating point, I think the option was introduced with Enterprise PL/I V4.4) the following happens:

- the literal `-2.34e-1` is converted to its internal representation as `bin float(6)`, i.e. short binary floating point
- the literal `'-2.34e-1'` is compared with a `bin float(6)` value, so it has to be converted to a `bin float` as well
- since `-0.234` does not have an exact representation as a binary fraction it seems the compiler converts it to a `bin float(54)`, i.e. an extended binary floating point value, to get maximum precision.
- So since `-0.234` has an infinite number of digits after the decimal point in its binary representation but the two converted values preserve a different number of digits the values do not compare equal.

Under `FLOAT(DFP)` (i.e. when using the machines DFP support)

- the internal representation of the literal `-2.34e-1` is an actual decimal floating point and thus exact
- as is the representation of `'-2.34e-1'`
- so under this compile-option both compare equal and the output of your program is `'1'b`

So your problem is a combination of the compilers different choice of data-representation and resulting rounding-errors from using binary floating point of different precision.

Comment: This demonstrates one of the pitfalls of floating-point value equality comparison. @piet.t thank you for performing the test compilations. By any chance, did you turn on the LIST option and look at the generated code?

Comment: Thank you a lot! The problem turned up complicated enough. I thought the answer would be much easier.